# is to be used only vs is to be only used

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

I have some trouble with putting an adverb to a sentence. Which one is correct in the following sentences.

- This fire extinguisher is to be used only in an emergency.

Or

- This fire extinguisher is to be only used in an emergency.

I studied the adverbs part in a grammar book. It says that the adverb is located after "be verb" and before other verbs.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to ELL. Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/200483/used-only-to-test-or-only-used-to-test) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is correct:

> "This fire extinguisher is to be used only in an emergency."

Alternatively, you could say:

> "This fire extinguisher is only to be used in an emergency."

Both mean essentially the same thing and would be clearly understood by a native speaker.

Your second example, however, is not what a native speaker would say:

> "This fire extinguisher is to be only used in an emergency."

I believe it to be grammatically correct but it would not be said this way by a native speaker.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st one sounds correct and 2nd doesn't.
2nd. one could maybe say "This Fire extinguisher is ONLY to be used in an Emergency."